# Import an API using the link in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have two different subscriptions, so I try to import an API to one subscription from another subscription.

I don't know what I’m doing wrong in calling the service to read to import as I’m getting 500 Internal server error.

Below are the screenshots for giving me a direction to do the right way to import a service from the link.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link if it returns a valid swagger/wadl and if it's accessible publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Exporting your Api from **new** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-import-api/#export-api
and   importing it to **newtrail** using the same format (WADL/Swagger)     https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-import-api/#import-api

Comment: Be sure to check the Swagger document, some of the endpoints/URLs in there are replaced with the API management endpoint/URLs.